# How to select string contains all substrings in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select row from table, which contains ONLY ALL substrings. For example, I have table `CAR_DESCRIPTION` that contains rows with values in column `Desc` like this:

```
tesla is super car
bmw is cool car
opel is budget car
```

And I want to select only the first row (tesla is super car) by specifying this substring (tesla, car), other rows no.

How to do it?

And I don't know how many words need to compare (it can be difference).

Comment: And is it using in sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `LIKE` with `%` as joker

```
create table cars(car varchar(50));
insert into cars values
('tesla is super car'),
('bmw is cool car'),
('opel is budget car');
select * from cars
where car like '%tesla%super%';
```

Returns

```
car  
Tesla is super car
```

If we write

```
where car like '%tesla%' and car like '%super%
```

The words can be in either order.
It's not clear what you are looking for the following example might help:

```
WHERE 
   (car LIKE '%tesla%' AND car like '%super%') 
      OR 
   (car LIKE '%mazda%' AND car like '%racing%')
```

Comment: You write bad answer. I don't know how many words need to compare (it can be difference). It can be tesla super or can be another words (1,2,3 ... 10 words) not only tesla super.

Comment: Please explain better which strings should match and which should be rejected.

Comment: Your answer right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the like function, which returns all the rows where characters are similar to the ones you put in the quotation.